# Destination unreachable (Host administratively prohibited)

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I'm using a host-only network in virtualbox.

The host (Windows): 192.168.56.1/24

The guest (CentOS): 192.168.56.101/24

There's a simple http server which listens on 0.0.0.0:8080 running in the guest.
"curl http://192.168.56.101:8080/" in the guest machine is OK. But it doesn't work in the host (visited by a browser as curl isn't installed on my Windows).

Ping 192.168.56.101 from the host is OK though. I try to gain some hints by capturing packets on the VirualBox-Host-Only-Network adapter with wireshark. And I see some ICMP packets sent from 192.168.56.101 to 192.168.56.1 which tell me "Destination unreachable (Host administratively prohibited)".

I can visit http://192.168.56.101:8080/ only if I shut down the firewall of the guest (`systemctl stop firewalld`). But I don't want to do that. **I'd like to visit http://192.168.56.101:8080/ from the host while the firewall of the guest is on.**

---

I have searched this for a while and still don't know exactly how. Maybe something with iptables but not familiar with it and feel a little hard to understand. Can someone explain how the following rules work to reject my visit and how to modify it properly (for example in the above situation)?

Thank you.

---

```
iptables -nvL --line-numbers (when the firewall is off)

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 72 packets, 6371 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 51 packets, 9866 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

```
iptables -nvL --line-numbers (when the firewall is on)

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
3        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
5        1    76 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
6        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
7       11  1096 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
8       11  1096 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
9       11  1096 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
11      11  1096 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
5        0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
6        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
8        0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
9        0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10       0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
11       0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
12       0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
13       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
14       0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 1204 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
2       12  1204 OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  enp0s8 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
2        0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  enp0s3 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
3        0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      enp0s8  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
2        0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      enp0s3  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
3        0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (3 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (3 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3        0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       11  1096 IN_public  all  --  enp0s8 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
2        0     0 IN_public  all  --  enp0s3 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
3        0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (3 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       11  1096 IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2       11  1096 IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3       11  1096 IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

With `ip addr`:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.56.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

Interface enp0s3 is to use NAT and enp0s8 connects to host-only network. Both lo and virbr0 are not relevant and not listed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `firewall-cmd`, [open the port](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_firewalld.html#sec-Opening_Ports_in_the_firewall-CLI) `8080/tcp`, once in the active rules (only triggering a rebuild of the `iptables` rules with the change) and once in the saved configuration (only saving the change in the configuration in `/etc/firewalld/`).

```
# firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp
success
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
success
```

---

UPDATE: allow a whole interface, as asked in comment.

`firewalld` has a concept of zones. By default actions are done on the `public` zone., but there are many predefined zones, eg `dmz`, `work`, ... and the `trusted` zone which implicitly trusts everything.  The easiest to allow an interface, is to add this interface to the `trusted` zone. As usual the two command are, once for the configuration (with `--permanent`) once for the active set (without `--permanent`. `--reload` could also work).

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-interface=enp0s8
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=enp0s8
```

iptables rules will have rules changed accordingly with among them those key rules, visible in the output of `iptables-save` (I'm just writing a few here, there are many more):

```
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i enp0s8 -j FWDI_trusted
-A FWDI_trusted -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_ZONES -i enp0s8 -j IN_trusted
-A IN_trusted -j ACCEPT
```

Now for example a remote incoming tcp connection to a random port (on an address) on this interface will likely switch from "No route to host" or other "Destination unreachable" error to "Connection refused" error unless there really is a process listening on it.

There are some issues, possibly distribution-dependent for it to always work properly, including after reboot, even if it appears to be fine at start. Example:

[Firewalld Adding Interfaces to a Zone Issue](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1455033)

Really, once going beyond the task of opening a few ports, using `firewalld` instead of directly making one own's rules with `iptables` can become convoluted, and requires investment in the knowledge of its syntax, which could have been spent in the lower layer's knowledge instead (today `iptables`, tomorrow `nft` ...), and requires *anyway* verifying the results today with `iptables-save` (tomorrow might become `nft list ruleset -a`).

Comment: Thank you. So I don't need to use the iptables command directly. Later I found there's no iptables service but only the iptables command installed in the guest.

Comment: After doing this a new line appeared under the IN_public_allow section:  "ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 ctstate NEW"

Comment: @miāo so is it working as intended or is there something still not working? If it's ok, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes, it works. I accept it now. And... Is there a way to allow all incoming connections of one interface (in this case the enp0s8) regardless of their port numbers?

Comment: You should ask an other question for this, or at the very least update the question. Anyway I'll update my answer accordingly